# Loading image background while scrolling in mobile

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

Hi i am developing a mobile application. Which follows the design like

I want to show the image of loading icon, with some greyed out background only on the content ie between footer and Header of my page.I am able to achieve it but the only problem i am facing is **while scrolling down in mobile
the position of greyed out background is moving down** . I tried by setting position fixed. still no improvements. Please take a look at the css:

```css
.loading {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 top: 95px;/*this is for setting the background greyed out position just after the header*/
 margin: 0;
 display: none;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 100;
 opacity: 0.6;
 background: rgba(0, 0, 0,0.3);
 -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
}

.loading img {
 position: absolute;
 top: 33%;
 left: 45%;
 background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap" data-role="page">
 <div data-role="header"></div>

 <div id="main" data-role="main" class="ui-content" data-theme="b">
  <div class="loading" id="loader">
   <img alt="" src="JQueryMobile/images/ajax-loader.gif" id="Img1" />
  </div>
 </div>
</div>

<div id='footer'>

</div>
```

Can anybody please help me , you can find the screen shot [Here](http://i62.tinypic.com/6gwwe9.jpg)

Comment: your comment in CSS isn't close normal ?

Comment: Could you add the basics to jsfiddle please?

Comment: did you have try using `position: fixed` for `.loading`? you may need specify `bottom:0`

Comment: i have created a fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/wcuxS/1312/....But actually the problem is in mobile while scrolling down

Comment: @pietro yes i tried fixed position already, and as well bottom:0

Comment: ok and why doesn't work ? i have done the change and it seems working  [http://jsfiddle.net/wcuxS/1314/](http://jsfiddle.net/wcuxS/1314/)

Comment: pietro thnx for ur help, but i added 'top' property there because i want to show background in between Header and footer and particularly on content of the page...